# Advice on entry form file uploads and S3

Tags: assets, s3, entry-form

Just planning out an entry form that includes a file upload field – an assets field hooked up to an S3 bucket. I see some documentation on entry form assets [here](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/assets-fields.html#templating), but need some advice on getting this working with S3 if anyone's done this before? Any help very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is a great learning resource. Worth the investment, IMO, if you're building a lot of sites with Craft CMS.
https://craftquest.io/lessons/switching-from-craft-local-assets-volume-to-s3